# Sinegy API signature, HMAC-SHA25, and encoded in base64 format

Tags: python, api, hmac

Can somebody help me with sinegy API signature? This is what they are asking:

> API methods that use full signed authentication requires api-key in the request header and api-signature in the request body.
>
> API signature is an encoded message which contains:
>
> Stringed request parameters 
> Method of API function 
> Path of API function 
> API secret
>
> These attributes must be separated by the vertical
> line | delimiter, hashed in HMAC-SHA25, and encoded in base64 format.

I don't have any experience with API signatures, this is what I tried so far:

```
secret = '$KDcKdsemlwJ6Vmj05f5NOQ4e.'

digest = hmac.new(
    secret.encode(),
    'ghjfghjfgh|fjkghkghj|ghjkghjk|ljklhjklh'.encode(),
    hashlib.sha256
)
signature = base64.b64encode(digest.digest())
```

This is what their example signature looks like: `8asufaol53wad`,
but what I receive is: `b'qCTV/psNaUdZt/F+0QMhDISb/n4yYuYrK7YG8aMCC7U='`

Here is their full API doc: https://docs.sinegy.com/#tag/Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
api_secret = "$KDcKdsemlwJ6Vmj05f5NOQ4e."
str_to_sign = "ghjfghjfgh|fjkghkghj|ghjkghjk|ljklhjklh"
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.